# AWS/Ansible - Is there a simple way of looking up the ID for a route53 health check using only the name tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I'm writing an ansible playbook which interacts with the AWS CLI.

I'd like to be able to look up a route53 health check based on its name tag.  For example, I'd like to be able to test whether a route53 health check already exists based on its name tag.  Alternatively, I'd like to be able to create an aggregate health check based on other health checks, so I need to be able to look up the ID of the child health checks based on their name tags.

I can look up a *list* of existing health checks:

```
aws route53 list-health-checks
```

However, this does not do what I need, since it returns details of all health checks, but only by ID. It does not return any detail about tags, for example:

```
UK165342:~ rsaunderson$ aws route53 list-health-checks
{
    "HealthChecks": [
        {
            "HealthCheckConfig": {
                "InsufficientDataHealthStatus": "LastKnownStatus",
                "Type": "CLOUDWATCH_METRIC",
                "AlarmIdentifier": {
                    "Region": "eu-west-1",
                    "Name": "my cloudwatch alert name"
                },
                "Inverted": false
            },
            "CallerReference": "20363f2b-f482-419d-a5bc-47646d68af90",
            "HealthCheckVersion": 1,
            "Id": "03ae403b-c33b-4568-8552-7931b2cadc0e"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can look up the tags for a health check, but only if I *already* know the ID for the healthcheck.  For example:

```
UK165342:~ rsaunderson$ aws route53 list-tags-for-resource --resource-type healthcheck --resource-id 5bb5e893-c50b-410c-9f84-b9ef3d5ee566
{
    "ResourceTagSet": {
        "ResourceType": "healthcheck",
        "ResourceId": "5bb5e893-c50b-410c-9f84-b9ef3d5ee566",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "some R53 health check name",
                "Key": "Name"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I *can* get the list of *all* healthcheck IDs, then look up the tags individually for each one, but this seems very inefficient.  Is there a better way to do this?  Possibly with a custom ansible module?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have the best (if inefficient) solution. There's no API in Route53 that allows to filter health checks based on their tags.